# Deleting N matching patterns using sed, awk, perl etc

Tags: python, perl, awk, sed

I have this situation, the file contains

```
abcd
line1
line2
line3
vwxyz
abcd
vwxyz
abcd
vwxyz
abcd
vwxyz
line4
line5
```

I would like to delete whenever I find matching 2 lines of

```
abcd
vwxyz
```

to be deleted so that it becomes

```
abcd
line1
line2
line3
vwxyz
line4
line5
```

I have search numerous stackoverflow suggestions of pattern matching but never encountered pattern matching of 2 lines

I have triend `sed -i '/abcd|vwxyz/d' file1` but that didn't work as expected...

Any help is appreciated using awk, sed, perl, pyhon etc

Comment: We thought you had tried something...Code?

Comment: sed -i '/abcd|vwxyz/d' file1 but that didn't work as expected

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/^abcd\nvwxyz$/d;P;D' file
```

Create a 2 line window  throughout the length of the file and delete that window if the current window matches the required strings. Otherwise print/delete the first line of the window and append another line, repeat.

This can be extended to match n lines:

```
sed ':a;N;s/[^\n]\+/&/2;Ta;/^abcd\nvwxyz$/d;P;D' file
```

generalised for 2 lines:

Or:

```
sed ':a;N;s/[^\n]\+/&/3;Ta;/^line1\nline2\nline3$/d;P;D' file
```

for 3 lines, etc.

An alternative:

```
sed -z 's/^abcd\nvwxyz\n//mg' file
```

Comment: Thanks, the 1st option seems simple enough...gotta knock my head for not thinking about \n :)

Comment: `^` means "start of string" not "start of line" so won't `sed -z 's/^...'` only match the text at the start of the file? I've no idea what the `m` before the `g` does though so maybe it's for "**m**agic"... :-).

Comment: @EdMorton the `m` flag following the substitution command is for multiline, where the `^` and `$` represent anchors for start/end of line.

Comment: @potong - ah, ok thanks for the explanation. That command line just output the input file unchanged when I tried it just now though with GNU sed 4.4-1.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks Ed I'm  currently on GNU sed 4.2.2 and do not experience this problem. Please use  the first solution  and perhaps if this error persists,  issue a bug report to the GNU sed maintainer. I believe the current version is GNU sed 4.7.

Answer (score 2):

you mean something like this?

```
sed '/abcd/{N;/vwxyz/d}' yourdata.file
```

**explanation**

```
/abcd/    # search first Pattern
{
N;        # if match read next line
/vwxyz/d  # if second pattern match then delete line
}
```

Comment: This might fail to delete a pair of lines if such a pair were preceded by `abcd`.

Answer (score 2):

With Perl, the simplest solution is to load the entire input into memory.

```
perl -0777pe's/abcd\nvwxyz\n//g'
```

If reading a line at a time, the generic solution in these types of problems is to keep a buffer of past lines.

```
if (!eof()) {
   my @buf = scalar(<>);
   while (<>) {
      if ($buf[-1] =~ /^abcd$/ && /^vwxyz$/) {
         @buf = ();
      } else {
         print(shift(@buf));
         push(@buf, $_);
      }
   }

   print @buf;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, considering your actual Input_file is same as shown samples.

```
awk -v RS="" '{gsub(/abcd\nvwxyz/,"");gsub(/[[:space:]]+\n/,ORS)} 1' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more cryptic than I'd like but with GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk -v RS='\nvwxyz\n' -v ORS= '!sub(/(^|\n)abcd$/,""){$0=$0 RT} 1' file
abcd
line1
line2
line3
vwxyz
line4
line5
```

Unfortunately if we're going with an RS-based solution (as opposed to keeping a rolling 2-line buffer or similar) then that's how it has to be done to accommodate the multi-line string appearing at the start and/or end of the file and/or in repeated blocks and/or starting/stopping in the middle of other lines. It can be used as-is for arbitrary long blocks of lines though:

```
awk -v RS='\nvwxyz\n' -v ORS= '!sub(/(^|\n)foo\nbar\netc\nabcd$/,""){$0=$0 RT} 1' file
```

or if you prefer:

```
awk -v RS='\nbar\netc\nabcd\nvwxyz\n' -v ORS= '!sub(/(^|\n)foo$/,""){$0=$0 RT} 1' file
```

Answer (score 0):

With `awk`, where you define your record separator as the 2 lines and you simply print each line.

```
awk -v RS='abcd\nvwxyz\n' '{printf $0}' file.in 
abcd
line1
line2
line3
vwxyz
line4
line5
```

---

A python solution:

```
import re

with open('file.in', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(re.sub(r'(^|\n)abcd\nvwxyz(?=\n)','',data), end='')
```

output:

```
python3 filter_lines.py 
abcd
line1
line2
line3
vwxyz
line4
line5
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS. Always use `printf "%s", $0` instead of `printf $0` as the latter will fail when $0 contains printf formatting characters such as `%s`. It should really be written as `awk -v RS='(^|\n)abcd\nvwxyz\n' '1'` though to handle the cases where `abcd` and/or `vwxyz` might appear mid-line and/or at the start and/or end of the file. I feel like that's still missing a case though....

Comment: Ah, yeah - the problem with that RS in my comment is it won't match the 2nd `\nabcd\nvwxy\n` when there's 2 consecutive blocks since it's consuming the `\n` at both ends of each block. I'd have to put some thought into the real RS necessary for this - it may simply not be an option.

Comment: After some thought - you can't do this robustly just by setting RS to the target multi-line string with surrounding line start/ends so I posted a new answer.